# How to call the same action of all tr of a table?

Tags: jquery

I've got this basic html:

```
<table class="myClass">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>content</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to remove all of the 'tr' on a button click.  I've tried the following with no luck.  What is the appropriate syntax here?

```
$('.myClass tr').each().remove();
$('.myClass tbody tr').each().remove();
$('.myClass tbody').each().remove(tr);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f5WQ7/1/  -> `$('#button').click(function() {
    $('.myClass tbody').children().remove();
});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just call [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) for the tr set

```
$('.myClass tr').remove();
```

Your code is failing because [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) expects a function as the argument, since it is not passed it will fail with an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined` so the rest of the actions will not get executed

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything else. Just use

```
$('.myClass tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('tr').bind('click',function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

This will remove each row on click event. But if you want to delete all the row on single button click than you should use-

```
$('.myClass tr').remove();
```

Comment: the OP wants to remove all the tr elements on the click of a button not the tr which was clicked on

Comment: I don't want to remove on the click of the tr.  Also, I'm no expert but I believe bind is deprecated and one should use `$(element).click(function(){...`